# jQuery button click handler to fill in form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, form

I have this function and not quite sure how to optimize it?

```
 function _onReadBtnClick(ctx) {

    var data = ctx.props.data;

    // Module Window -- Form Input Values 
    $(".modal-title").text("Intranet Module");
    $("#cBalModel").modal();
    $("#mBalDate").val(data.BalanceingDate);
    $("#mStoreCode").val(data.StoreCode);
    $("#mSubmittedBy").val(data.SubmittedBy);
    $("#mCustCode").val(data.CustomerCode);
    $("#mTicketSO").val(data.Ticket_SO);
    $("#mDollarAmt").val(data.DollarAmount);
    $("#mKeyedIn").val(data.KeyInAs);
    $("#mShouldBeIn").val(data.ShouldBe);
    $("#mAdditionalInfo").val(data.AdditionalInfo);
};
```

Comment: You can ditch jQuery for this bit and store the elements directly into an object/variables. This way, you don't have to re-re-re-re fetch the same elements. Also, only call `$("#cBalModel").modal();` after you changed all the text values. This will reduce the number of reflows to 1, instead of many.

Comment: What would that look like?

Comment: What does the function do?  What is the HTML on which it operates?  What is `ctx`?  What is `data` in `ctx`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can make sure that the fields' IDs have same names like the props, then you can do something like:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
    $("#"+key).val(obj[key]);
});
```

Comment: With some memoization, you could speed up this code by quite a bit. An example would be `var elems = {}; function _onReadBtnClick(ctx){ [...] Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
    (key in elems ? elems[key] : elems[key] = $("#"+key)).val(obj[key]);
});`. This would only fetch the element from the DOM if it isn't already in the object.